# Does a "climb and maintain" instruction override a "climb via the SID" one?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, sid-star

This question pertains to the [SNSHN THREE SID](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1802/00965SNSHN.PDF) out of [Ontario, CA (KONT)](http://airnav.com/airport/KONT).

Let's say I was originally cleared to "climb via the SNSHN departure except maintain 8,000". Then the clearance is amended after departure to "climb and maintain FL 240".

My question is, am I still required to cross NLAND at or above 14,000, as depicted in the SID?

Comment: Very closely related (in fact, it does contain your answer, but wasn't the main point of the question):  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1624/69

Answer (score 10):

If the controller issues a "climb via" SID with an interim altitude of 8,000 and then subsequently amends the altitude and states:

**"*Climb via SID* and maintain Flight Level 240"** then the altitude crossing restriction to cross INLAND at or above 14,000 **still applies**.

However, if the controller does not use the words "Climb Via," and instead states:

***Climb and maintain* Flight Level 240**" then the altitude crossing restriction to cross INLAND at or above 14,000 **is cancelled**.

The words "Climb Via" are essentially the same as "comply with all SID restrictions."  If a new altitude is issued without the "Climb Via" verbiage, then (unless the altitude crossing restrictions are restated) climb unrestricted to the new altitude is expected.

**From FAA JO Order 7110.65W, para. 4-5-6 and 4-5-7 (Air Traffic Controller's handbook)**:

> 6.
>   When an aircraft has been issued an interim
>   altitude  and  after  departure  ATC  can  subsequently
>   clear the aircraft to climb to the original top altitude
>   published  in  the  SID  instruct  aircraft  to  “**climb  via
>   SID.**” When issuing a new altitude and compliance
>   with  published  restrictions  is  still  required  instruct
>   aircraft to 
>   “climb via SID 
>   except maintain (altitude).”
>
> PHRASEOLOGY
>   −
>   CLIMB VIA SID.
>   CLIMB VIA SID except maintain (altitude).
>
> EXAMPLE
>   −
>   1. (An aircraft was issued the T
>   eddd One departure, “climb
>   via  SID”  in  the  IFR  departure  clearance.  An  interim
>   altitude of 10,000 was issued instead of the published top
>   altitude of FL 
>   230; after departure ATC is able to issue the
>   published top altitude): “Climb via SID.”
>   NOTE
>   −
>   In Example 1, the air
>   craft will track laterally and vertically
>   on the Teddd One departure and initially climb to 10,000;
>   Once  re-issued  the  “**climb  via**”  clearance  the  interim
>   altitude is 
>   cancelled aircraft
>    **will continue climb to FL230
>   while *complying with published restrictions***.
>   EXAMPLE
>   −
>   2. (Using Example 1, after departure ATC is able to issue
>   an altitude higher than the published top altitude):  “Climb
>   via SID except maintain flight level two six zero.”
>   NOTE
>   −
>   In Example 2, the air
>   craft will track laterally and vertically
>   on the Teddd One departure and initially climb to 10,000;
>   **once issued “climb via” clearance to FL260 the aircraft
>   will  continue  climb  while  complying  with  published
>   restrictions.**
>
> NOTE
>
> 1.
>   Considering the principle that the last ATC clearance
>   issued has precedence over the previous, the phraseology
>   **“maintain  (altitude)”  *alone***  **cancels  previously  issued
>   altitude  restrictions,  including  SID/STAR  altitude
>   restrictions**  unless  they  are  restated  or  modified,  and
>   authorizes  an  unrestricted  climb  or  descent.  Speed
>   restrictions r
>   emain in effect unless 
>   the controller explicitly
>   cancels the speed restrictions.
>   2.
>   Restate 
>   “climb/descend via” and then use “except” or
>   “except  maintain”  phraseology  to  modify  published
>   restrictions  or  assign  a  new  top/bottom  altitude.  Use
>   “resume” phraseology with “maintain” to rejoin a route
>   and assign a new altitude 
>   where 
>   compliance with published
>   altitude restrictions is not required.

[all preceding emphasis is mine]

Also see AIM para. 5-2-8.

Lastly, here is some good guidance regarding "Climb/Descend Via"
[Climb/Descend Via FAQ](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/afx/afs/afs400/afs470/pbn/media/Climb_Descend_Via_FAQ.pdf)

Comment: absolutely correct.